# issue with Apache POI when converting .docx to a json document format.

Tags: json, apache-poi

I am currntly parsing a 26 page .docx with images,tables,italics,underlines. I am able to clear

Using apache POI I created XWPF document format with list of XWPF paragraphs. When i iterate through XWPF paragraphs, I am not able to get styles (italics,underlines,bolds) for individual lines if a single paragraph contains different styles.

i have tried using XWPF.paragraph.getrun(). XWPF...run.getfamilyfont() i am getting null. But i get the data at the paragraph level when i run XWPF.paragraph.getstyle()

Please do let me know if you have encountered similar issues.

Comment: Without any code, it's hard for us to work out where you're going wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I hope these code can help you , you can get some style from CTRPr object.

```
CTRPr rPr = run.getCTR().getRPr();
if(rPr!=null){
    CTFonts rFonts = rPr.getRFonts();
    if(rFonts!=null){
        String eastAsia = rFonts.getEastAsia();
        String hAnsi = rFonts.getHAnsi();
        Enum hAnsiTheme = rFonts.getHAnsiTheme();

    }
}
```